# A fancy random dynamical system

Tags: reference-request, dynamical-systems, markov-chains

I want some reference that might be helpful on this problem:

Let $n,N\in\mathbb{N}$, $n\geq 1$ and $N \geq 4$.

Let $\mathcal{X} = S^{n\times N - 1} \cup \{0\}$. Suppose that $\mathcal{X} = \bigcup_{\gamma \in \Gamma}\mathcal{X}_\gamma$ where $\mathcal{X}_\gamma \cap \mathcal{X}_{\gamma'} = \emptyset$ if $\gamma \neq \gamma'$, $|\Gamma| < \infty$, and $m(\partial \mathcal{X}_\gamma) = 0$ (all the boundaries have zero lebesgue measure).

Let $\Sigma$ be a finite set of symbols and let $T_\lambda^\gamma$ be an invertible linear transformation for each $(\lambda, \gamma)\in \Sigma\times \Gamma$  and define, for each $\lambda\in\Sigma$ a function $f_\lambda: \mathcal{X} \to \mathcal{X}$ by
$$ \rho \mapsto \begin{cases}\frac{T_\lambda^\gamma \rho}{\|T_\lambda^\gamma \rho\|}, & \text{if }\rho \in \mathcal{X}_\gamma\text{ and } \|T_\lambda^\gamma \rho\|> 0, \\
0, & \text{otherwise}.
\end{cases} $$

That is, each function $f_\lambda$ when restricted to $\mathcal{X}_\gamma$ is a normalized linear transformation. But has discontinuities on the frontier of those sets.

Now let $\mu$ be a measure on $\Sigma$ and construct the random dynamical system as usual by choosing some $\lambda \sim \mu$ at each iteraction and updating the state by applying $f_\lambda$.

I want to understand the dynamics of this system. Under which condition on the transformations $T_\lambda^\gamma$ we have dense orbits, ergodicity (with the lebesgue measure) or even mixing properties? It seems a little like the baker's map, but it is just my intuition.

Comment: You can start with a sum of two eigenvectors with different eigenvalues. I would forget about zero and do everything on the projective space as usual. For the rest, you need to show some work of yours first (there are many related works, but tend to be quite nontrivial, it is peculiar to ask that here).